# Simple list of tuples with wrong print

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, using CPython. I'm reading how to use lists and tuples properly, so I've designed a really simple program to see if I know what I'm doing, but as I can see, there is something wrong in theory and I don't know what is

I've designed 2 functions: foo and foo2, intendend to print the same result, but it's not.

```py
# Wrong output
def foo(v):
    print(v[:][0])

# Right output
def foo2(v):
    for i in range(0, 2):
        print(v[i][0])

v = [('ABC', 'DEF', 1), ('ABC2', 'DEF2', 2)]
foo(v)
foo2(v)
```

RESULT:
Output from foo: ('ABC', 'DEF', 1)
Output from foo2: ABC ABC2

EXPECTED:
Output from foo: ABC ABC2
Output from foo2: ABC ABC2

What is hapenning here?

Comment: standard list doesn't works like numpy array. `[:][0]` doesn't get first elements from all data in list. In numpy array you could use `v[:,0]` to get list `['ABC' 'ABC2']` - but you still have to use  `" ".join()` or `for`-loop to correctly display it.

Comment: In the Python shell, what do you get when you enter `v[:]`? Of possible interest: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `foo`, you pass in a list of tuples, and operate on it with `v[:]`.
All this is doing is basically making a copy of the list you passed in.
Demonstrably:

```
>>> v
[('ABC', 'DEF', 1), ('ABC2', 'DEF2', 2)]
>>> v[:]
[('ABC', 'DEF', 1), ('ABC2', 'DEF2', 2)]
```

So, when you access the first element of `v[:]`, all you get back is the tuple `('ABC', 'DEF', 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`v[:]` does nothing other than duplicate the list, it's a list slice that goes from start to end of the list

if you want to make this short you could use `zip(*v)`, zip((1,2), (3,4)) combines 1 with 3 and 2 with 4. the `*` star operator is used to get elements from a list as separate function arguments

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [:] does not do anything, so you are just printing the first 
entry of the list,

which is the tuple ('ABC', 'DEF', 1)

In foo2, you are first picking a tuple ([ i ]), and then the first entry of the tuple ([0]).

Comment: well, the `[:]` does something... it is creating a new, shallow-copy of the list